# How do I restrict style to affect content only in modal?

Tags: html, css

Goal: With minimal changes (preferably none) to an existing style sheet, how can I contain it's effect to a modal so that it doesn't change the underlying page. For example

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/theme1.css"/>
  <head>
  <body>
    <div class="bodycontent>
      Some stuff
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/theme2.css"/>
      Modal Content
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Obviously, this will not work but hopefully it shows what I'm trying to achieve. In practice, this applys theme2.css to the whole page as opposed to just the modal. Is there a way for me to apply style to only the modal without having to go into theme2.css and put .modal before every rule?

**Edit for clarity**
I'm essentially building a theme switcher with the preview in a modal and I don't like my base page getting affected. Also, suppose the themes I'm using are very long and I'm trying to avoid two large css files, one for the preview in the modal and one for when the theme is actually used on a page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to write your CSS in such a way that `.modal` only inherits appropriate styles from more general CSS selectors that apply to it (e.g. the `body` CSS properties).

Any selector that needs to apply specifically to the modal and to the modal alone should be prefixed with `.modal` and any styles it inherits that you do not want need to be overwritten in this manner (it may help to give the modal an ID which has higher specificity and will make it easier to overwrite said properties).

I understand you may find that inconvenient, but you should have designed your CSS this way in the first place.  There is no way to 'cancel' CSS inheritance for a specific DOM node that I am aware of.

**EDIT:** If you populate the modal content with an iframe (which is supported by most decent modal window scripts) you can in fact do it the way you are asking - styles from the page will not interfere with styles inside of an iframe, and that way you can include the modal styles directly in the iframe (in the iframe `head` or as an external `link`) like you want.

Comment: For clarity, I'm trying to avoid having two different css files with the only difference being one has .modal in front of every rule as the theme will also be on pages. The modal is just a preview. Snark about what I should have done aside, I'll give this question the answered check in 24 hours if a solution hasn't been posted.

Comment: So don't use different css files then?  Use one and separate out sections by comments (if you so desire).

Comment: @GeoffreyOchsner You don't need 2 CSS files, just add your `.modal` rules to the same file (this is preferable as you always want to minimize your number of GET requests).  Your modal must have some pretty complex styling for this to be an issue.

Comment: @GeoffreyOchsner have you considered using an iframe to populate the content of the modal? Most modal scripts have this option, and that way the stylesheet of the main page will not be inherited by the modal content (since it's in an iframe).  That way you can just put your modal styles in the iframe.

Comment: @GeoffreyOchsner and don't take the snark the wrong way, I'm just snarky :)

Comment: Let me try again. The modal is JUST a preview of what html will look like when a theme is applied. Then the person can "publish" for lack of a better term the html with style sheet. So I WOULD need 2 css files. One for the preview where every rule looks like .modal .body{font:12px ...} and one for the page they publish that just has .body{font:12px...}. Maybe not need but I'm trying to avoid doubling the amount of rules I write for every theme.

Comment: @GeoffreyOchsner Okay, that makes a bit more sense! In that case, probably the easiest way to do it is with the iframe method I suggested in my edit, but it will still be a bit tricky as you would need to dynamically update the iframe to load the desired stylesheet (which might need a little bit of AJAX to serve the appropriate iframe or render the appropriate `link` in the iframe before it is displayed).

Comment: Upvoting the **EDIT** -- I agree, an iframe is the way to go.

Comment: I like this iframe idea. I'm giving it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
/*body content styles go here*/
.bodycontent p {}
.bodycontent a {}
.bodycontent h1 {}

/*modal content styles go here*/
.modal p {}
.modal a {}
.modal h1 {}
```

This way you keep all your styles in one sheet, but you prefix the selectors with the parent class/id.

Unless your modal is ajax, or iframe, then this is the only way to do this. Even if you used SASS and wrote:

```
.modal {
  .a {}
  .p {}
  .h1 {}
}
```

it would still compile to the above.